# Implementing Dynamic Forms in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing is correct. Basically I have a page which contains multiple components. One of the components, `DynamicRequestorDetails`, gets passed a list of possible components to be added to it (eg. textbox or dropdown). This one works and the textboxes/dropdowns are generated. My problem is the `handleChange` event of the parent container doesn't seem to get passed to the dynamic components generated by the componentHandler. Is there anything else I missed? I see the values are passed correctly but during debugging it seems like the `handleChange` event is not being triggered by the dynamically created components.

I have the following files:

Dropdown Component:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';

const Dropwdown = ({identifier, value, selectChanged, options, label}) => {    
    return (
        <div className="row eis-field-row">
            <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold">{label}</label>
            <select className="col-xs-6"
                name={identifier}
                id={identifier}
                onChange={selectChanged}
                value={value}
            >
                <option value="">--Please select one--</option>
                {
                options.map((option) => {
                    return <option key={option.Value} value={option.Value}>{option.Text}</option>;
                })
            }                
            </select>
        </div>
    );
};

Dropwdown.propTypes = {
    identifier: PropTypes.string,
    defaultOption: PropTypes.object,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    selectChanged: PropTypes.func,
    options: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    label: PropTypes.string

};

export default Dropwdown;
```

Component Handler:

```
import React from 'react';

/* import components here */
import Textbox from '../components/common/forms/Textbox';
import Dropdown from '../components/common/forms/Dropdown';

/* import component types */
import * as types from '../constants/FieldTypes';

export function getFieldValue(fieldValues, identifier) {
    let selectedItem = fieldValues.find(x => x.FieldID == identifier);
    if(Object.keys(selectedItem).length > 0) {
        return selectedItem.Value;
    }    
}

export function RenderComponent(field, handleChange, value) {
    switch(field.Type) {
        case types.TextComponent: {           
            return (
                <Textbox
                    type="text"
                    label={field.Label}
                    id={field.Identifier}
                    name={field.Identifier}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    placeholder={field.Placeholder}
                    key={field.Identifier}
                />
            );
        }

        case types.SelectComponent: {
            return (
                <Dropdown
                    name={field.Identifier}
                    label={field.Label}
                    id={field.Identifier}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={value}
                    options={field.Options}
                    key={field.Identifier}
                />
            );
        }

        default: {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

DynamicRequestorDetails Component:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import * as ch from '../../utilites/componentHandler';

const DynamicRequestorDetails = ({userinfo, ccValue, handleChange, isVisible, customFields, fieldValues}) => {
    let wrapperClass = " hidden";
    if(!isVisible) {
        wrapperClass = "";
    } else {
        wrapperClass = " hidden";
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <label className="label-headers TheSansBold">REQUESTOR DETAILS</label>
            <div className="row eis-field-row">
                <label className="TheSansBold col-xs-4">Name</label>
                <label id="requestorName" className="col-xs-6 field-value">{userinfo.DisplayName}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="row eis-field-row">
                <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold ">Employee No</label>
                <label className="col-xs-6 field-value">{userinfo.LanId}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="row eis-field-row">
                <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold">Department</label>
                <label className="col-xs-6 field-value">{userinfo.Department}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="row eis-field-row">
                <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold">Designation</label>
                <label className="col-xs-6 field-value">{userinfo.Title}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="row eis-field-row">
                <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold">Contact No</label>
                <label className="col-xs-6 field-value">{userinfo.Mobile}</label>
            </div>
            <div id="reqDivsion" className={"row eis-field-row" + wrapperClass}>
                <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold">Divsion</label>
                <select className="col-xs-6" onChange={handleChange}>
                    <option value="1">--Select Division--</option>
                    <option value="2">Group 1</option>
                    <option value="3">Group 2</option>
                    <option value="4">Group 3</option>
                    <option value="5">Group 4</option>
                    <option value="6">Group 5</option>
                    <option value="7">Group 6</option>
                </select>
            </div>            
            <div className={"row eis-field-row" + wrapperClass}>
                <label className="col-xs-4 TheSansBold">Cost Center: </label>
                <input type="text" value={ccValue} onChange={handleChange} className="col-xs-6" />
            </div>
            {
                customFields.map(customField => {
                    let fieldValue = ch.getFieldValue(fieldValues, customField.Identifier);
                    return ch.RenderComponent(customField, handleChange, fieldValue);
                })
            }            
        </div>
    );
};

DynamicRequestorDetails.propTypes = {
    userinfo: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    ccValue: PropTypes.string,
    handleChange: PropTypes.func,
    divChange: PropTypes.func,
    isVisible: PropTypes.bool,
    customFields: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
    fieldValues: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
};

export default DynamicRequestorDetails;
```

Parent Component:

```
const steps = def.ProcessPages[0].Steps;

class NewSMILEPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            FieldValues: []
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateFieldValues();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if(newProps.smile.FieldValues != this.props.smile.FieldValues) {
            this.setState({FieldValues: newProps.smile.FieldValues});
        }
    }

    handleChange(e, identifier) {

    }

    populateFieldValues() {
        //populates values for my state
    }

    updateFieldValues(fv) {
        //updates values for my state
    }

    goBack() {
        //do some action
    }    

    render() {
        if(this.state.FieldValues.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-4">
                            <FormHeader formName={this.props.eforms.SelectedEForm.Title} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-xs-8">
                            <StepTracker steps={def.ProcessPages[0].Steps} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/*Step Name and Image*/}
                    <div className="row form-label-container">
                        <img src={HeaderImage} alt="Header Image" width="40" className="pull-left"/>
                        <p className="form-header pull-left TheSansBold">NEW REQUEST</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-6 pull-left">
                            <DynamicRequestorDetails
                                userinfo={this.props.userinfo}
                                isVisible={this.props.isVisible} 
                                ccValue=""
                                ccValueChange={this.handleChange}
                                divChange={this.divisionChange}
                                customFields={def.ProcessPages[0].Fields}
                                handleChange={this.handleChange}
                                fieldValues={this.state.FieldValues}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row footer-button-container footer">
                        <div className="pull-left">
                            <button id="btnBack" type="button" className="btn btn-back" onClick={this.goBack} >CANCEL</button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                            <button id="btnNext" type="button" className="btn btn-next margin-right-lg" onClick={this.goNext}>NEXT</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            );
        } else {
            return (<h1>Loading</h1>);
        }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        //state to props returned here      
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        //actions returned here
    };
}

NewSMILEPage.propTypes = {
    //prop checking done here
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NewSMILEPage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter names mismatch selectChanged/handleChange, missing `selectChanged`...

You're using `onChange` on component in `RenderComponent` - it works like passing prop with that name, not assigning handler. `onChange` should be used in render on 'normal' html elements only.

Comment: Than you so much! Sometimes I feel stupid asking these questions specially when I realize the answer. It looks simple but I usually miss items like these.